# Create a list of nodes from a graph in Prolog?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, graph-theory

I'm trying to use the information from edges in a graph. I want to create a list of nodes from the edges in the graph I'm given. For example:

```
? - graph([edge(1,2),edge(2,3),edge(3,4)],List).
List = [1,2,3,4]
```

Here's a base case:

```
graph([edge(X,Y)],[X,Y]).
```

I have no idea how to do this, without a knowledge base. And why doesn't this just work on its own? Or something like this?

```
graph([edge(X,Y)], List) :- append(X,Y,List).
```

I'm very new to Prolog and would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a  solution that uses only basic Prolog:
I think the base case should be the empty graph, not the graph with just one element. It has no nodes:

```
nodes([],[]).
```

For every non-empty graph, you collect the two nodes of the first edge, then continue with the rest of the graph:

```
nodes([edge(X,Y)|RestGraph],[X,Y|RestNodes]) :-
  nodes(RestGraph,RestNodes).
```

The problem with this solution is that you have a node probably several times in the result. You can eliminate such duplicates with sort/2:

```
nodes2(Graph,Nodes) :- nodes(Graph,Unsorted), sort(Unsorted,Nodes).
```

CapelliC's solution is more elegant and concise, but maybe harder to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

`without a knowledge base` is a weird statement. If you have some edge/2, you can easily collect all nodes identifiers with with snippet:

```
nodes(Ns) :- setof(N, M^(edge(N, M) ; edge(M, N)), Ns).
```

*edit* Given code from comment, I would suggest

```
nodes_of_graph(graph(Edges), Ns) :-
  setof(N, M^(member(edge(N, M), Edges) ; member(edge(M, N), Edges)), Ns).
```

yields

```
1 ?- nodes_of_graph(graph([edge(1,2),edge(1,3)]),L).
L = [1, 2, 3].
```

Comment: By knowledge base, I mean I don't have a set of rules for the edges (e.g. edge(a,b), edge(a,c), etc.). Maybe I used the wrong term. If I were to say ?- graph([edge(1,2),edge(1,3)]) I want to create [1,2,3].

Answer (score 1):

Carlo's solution can be improved by avoiding the performance penalty of the double call to `member/2` by using an auxiliary predicate for the `setof/3` goal. For example:

```
nodes_of_graph(graph(Edges), Nodes) :-
    setof(Node, edge_node(Edges, Node), Nodes).

edge_node(Edges, Node) :-
    member(edge(Begin, End), Edges),
    (   Node = Begin
    ;   Node = End
    ).
```

This alternative also improves readability (but at the cost of adding one more auxiliary predicate).